# How to addEventListener to a button in popup content of ArcGIS API for JS

Tags: javascript, popup, arcgis-js-api

I have created a custom popup with the popupTemplate function with ArcGIS JS API 4.x

And i add a button in popup content by html.

but i can not addEventListener to a button in popup.

here is the way i am try to do now:
((the full code is here:https://codepen.io/llllllllc/pen/mdpabGw))

1. return html to create button in popup content

```
const popupTemplate = {
                // autocasts as new PopupTemplate()
                title: "Population in {NAME}",
                content: populationChange,
                };

                layer.popupTemplate = popupTemplate;

                function populationChange(feature) 
                {
                    const div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.innerHTML =
                        "<input type='button' id='btn' value='CLICK'>";
                    return div;
                }
```

2. watch content change

```
view.popup.watch("content", (newValue, oldValue, propertyName, target) => {......});
```

3.querySelector("#btn") then addEventListener but it fail ,and console.log(btn) show btn is null

```
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
console.log(btn)
btn.addEventListener(
    "click",
    function () {
        lert("HELLO WORLD!");
    },
   false
);
```

[the consol show like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8v79.png)

Any help much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

i think i figure it out !

i try to do querySelector to "const div" before it return and it works!

```
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML ="<input type='button' id='btn' value='CLICK'>";
const btn = div.querySelector("#btn");
btn.addEventListener(......);
return div
```